# How to block url or .js file execution on a specific using greasemonkey script? (client side)

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts

I want to stop a javascript .js to load on a specific website with greasemonkey/violentmonkey scrpit

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js
```

This is the script that loads on pagesource:

```
<script async="" crossorigin="anonymous" data-hljs-style="github-gist" integrity="sha384-TB2DTH77ndX7xwCHAtxD7BZqyn4r429ZSoGL7vcrb5x0bFSvLGAMoiriMUcIqeTu" onload="hljsLoader.highlightBlocks(this.parentNode)" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js"></script>
```

This is the url I want to stop loading on a webpage because it highlights code with syntax highlihgting, I want to stop syntax highlight.

If I block it on browser using ublock origin it works but I want to block it with userscript.

Edit:
I used the script as suggested but it is not working, what could I be doing wrong?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        New script 
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       *flarum.org*
// @include     *flarum.org*
// @grant       none
// @version     1.0
// @run-at      document-start
// @author      -
// @description 12/26/2020, 9:57:34 AM
// ==/UserScript==

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(({ addedNodes }) => {
    addedNodes.forEach((addedNode) => {
      if (addedNode.nodeType === 1 && addedNode.matches('script') && addedNode.src === 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js') {
        addedNode.remove();
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Am I missing something?

Here is the url That I'm trying to run script on
https://discuss.flarum.org/d/25739-disable-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method below usually works but something seems to be interfering with it on your page for some reason. An ugly workaround is to put an empty hljs property on the window in advance, so that the page script, when run, thinks it already exists and does nothing:

```
window.hljsLoader = {};
```

---

You can add a MutationObserver to the document at the beginning of pageload and watch for the addition of a script tag which has that URL as a src, and remove it. Make sure you're using `@run-at document-start`, and then do:

```
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(({ addedNodes }) => {
    addedNodes.forEach((addedNode) => {
      if (addedNode.nodeType === 1 && addedNode.matches('script') && addedNode.src === 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js') {
        addedNode.remove();
        observer.disconnect();
      }
    });
  });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Although the script tag will get temporarily added to the DOM, it will be removed in the observer microtask before it gets a chance to run.

Live snippet of the script working:

```html
<script>
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(({ addedNodes }) => {
    [...addedNodes].forEach((addedNode) => {
      if (addedNode.nodeType === 1 && addedNode.matches('script') && addedNode.src === 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js') {
        console.log('Script tag addition intercepted and removed');
        addedNode.remove();
        observer.disconnect();
        console.log('hljsLoader has not been loaded:', typeof hljsLoader);
      }
    });
  });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
</script>

<script async="" crossorigin="anonymous" data-hljs-style="github-gist" integrity="sha384-TB2DTH77ndX7xwCHAtxD7BZqyn4r429ZSoGL7vcrb5x0bFSvLGAMoiriMUcIqeTu" onload="console.log(hljsLoader)" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js"></script>
```

If there are multiple scripts, you'll have to loop through them rather than stop on the first:

```js
console.log(typeof hljsLoader);

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(typeof hljsLoader);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script>
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
  mutations.forEach(({ addedNodes }) => {
    [...addedNodes].forEach((addedNode) => {
      if (addedNode.nodeType === 1 && addedNode.matches('script') && addedNode.src === 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js') {
        console.log('Script tag addition intercepted and removed');
        addedNode.remove();
        console.log(typeof hljsLoader);
      }
    });
  });
});
observer.observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => observer.disconnect());
</script>

<script async="" crossorigin="anonymous" data-hljs-style="github-gist" integrity="sha384-TB2DTH77ndX7xwCHAtxD7BZqyn4r429ZSoGL7vcrb5x0bFSvLGAMoiriMUcIqeTu" onload="console.log(hljsLoader)" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js"></script>
<script async="" crossorigin="anonymous" data-hljs-style="github-gist" integrity="sha384-TB2DTH77ndX7xwCHAtxD7BZqyn4r429ZSoGL7vcrb5x0bFSvLGAMoiriMUcIqeTu" onload="console.log(hljsLoader)" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/s9e/hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I have added the loaded script from pagesource, Can you please add above code with it, I don't have much knowledge of this script.

Comment: It should work, the `src` is just as you said it was, and that's all the mutation observer callback checks for

Comment: Nope it's not working, hljs-loader@1.0.16/loader.min.js is still loading on the webpage along with syntax highlighting the code

Comment: Works just fine here, see live snippet. Make sure your userscript is running on `document-start`, as the answer says.

Comment: I see your script is working perfecting on snippet but why is it not working for me? I edited the first post with more details

Comment: Your question only showed one script, but it looks like the page has not one script, but lots and lots of such scripts for that endpoint, so you'll have to wait until the page loads to disconnect the observer, instead of stopping at the first script found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226433/discussion-between-imhd3d-and-certainperformance).

Comment: Where do I put window.hljsLoader = {}; ? In my userscript?

Comment: Yes, that can be the whole script, nothing else is needed

Comment: I found a case where the script will be loaded nonetheless in Google Chrome. I'm not sure why. 
Try `<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-12345678-9"></script>` The network call happens even if the mutation observer removes the script. Is this a bug in Chrome, or the mutation observer?

Comment: @alev I think in some circumstances it's impossible to block the network call, but you should still be able to prevent the requested resource from being put onto the page with `.remove()` in the observer.